# Converting JSON and building a Dictionary using Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, nsjsonserialization

I have a very complex JSON data. And I tried to parse using objective c programming. The JSON data looks like the following (Here, I presented the simple format to explain. But it has very deep leveling):

```
{
    "university": "CUNY",
    "results": {
        "Engineering": 200,
        "Computer Science": 298,
        "Life Science": 28
    }
}
```

Using `NSJSONSerialization`, I tried to solve this and I use the following code:

```
NSDictionary *parsedObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:NULL];
[parsedObject objectForKey:@"results"];
```

And getting the result. But I need a dictionary like `myResultDict` which will be made form the `results` so that I can implement other functionality.

Can anybody give me a small hint how to do that?

Comment: Your second line retrieves the results dictionary, but doesn't do anything with it. You need to assign the result of that expression to a variable of type `NSDictionary *`

Comment: Got it! NSDictionary * = parsedObject objectForKey:@"results"];   :)

Comment: Also for something as potentially error-prone as this, don't miss the opportunity to trap and report errors (i.e. check `parsedObject != nil` and then report the error (which you have set to `NULL`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you get the parsed data by using `NSJSONSerialization` it will give you parsed dictionary with multiple key-value pairs.

Then by fetching results key you can get your result dictionary.

For example:

```
NSDictionary *myResultDict = [parsedDictionary objectForKey:@"results"];
```

Comment: Note: use `objectForKey` not `valueForKey`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this method:

```
NSDictionary *dic = @{@"university": @"CUNY", @"results" : @{@"Engineering": @200, @"Computer Science": @298, @"Life Science": @28}};

[self getSubDictionaryWithDictionary:dic];
```

This method only logs the values inside `NSDictionary`, if you want to handle `NSArray` kind of class, up to you.. :)

```
- (void)getSubDictionaryWithDictionary:(NSDictionary *)dictionary
{
    for (id key in [dictionary allKeys])
    {
        id object = [dictionary objectForKey:key];

        NSLog(@"key:%@ value:%@",key, object);

        if ([object isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]])
        {
            [self getSubDictionaryWithDictionary:object];
        }  
    }
}
```

This extract all the dictionary inside the nested dictionary, you can modify it depending from what you need.. :)

Hope this is helpful.. Cheers.. :)